# Button clicks Xamarin Android project only working once

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

I have a project I have created on Xamarin for Android and I am having a problem with my buttons. They work perfectly fine on the first click but seem to crash out when I click them again (eg multiple login attempts).

The code I am using to create this click event is this:

```
 loginClick.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
         // CODE THAT DOES WORK
         loginClick.SetOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

I have this function in my class file called OnClick which is empty and looks like this:
[image]

If I don't have that function I can't implement the OnClickListener view which I need for my button. However when I click the button once it goes into the click function I have created for it (inside the OnCreate function). When I click the button again it goes into this OnClick function on not the one I have created.

Anyone got any idea why this is happening and how I can get around it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xamarin/C# normalization of using an EventHander for an Android view `Click` uses a listener internally, so by starting off using the C# `EventHander` and then adding an `OnClickListener` within that event, you are breaking the event's listener. Use one or the other, but **not both**.

```
button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
button.SetOnClickListener(this);
```

#### Or

```
button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
button.Click += delegate
{
   ~~~~
}
```

Comment: so when I use delegate I don't need to set an onclicklistener?

Comment: @broliverparker Correct, one or the other, just not both